# How to deregister click listener in Angular component?

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

How do I get rid of a document click listener when an Angular component is destroyed?

Simplified demo code:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="TestingCtrl as vm">

    <my-component ng-if="vm.showComponent"></my-component>

    <br><br><br>

    <button ng-click="vm.setShowState(false)">
      Destroy component
    </button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Javascipt:

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('TestingCtrl', function TestingCtrl() {
    this.showComponent = true;

  this.setShowState = function(state) {
    this.showComponent = state;
  }
})

.component('myComponent', {  
  bindings: {
    name: '@'
  },
  template: 'myComponent',  
  controller: function ($document) {
    var listener;

    this.$onInit = function() {
        listener = $document.on('click', function () {
            console.log('You clicked on the document');
        });
    }

    this.$onDestroy = function() {
        console.log('$onDestory triggered');
        $document.off('click', listener);
    }

  }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HoffZ/L7scekj3/)

When clicking the button "Destroy component", the component gets removed from the DOM (with ng-if) and $onDestroy is triggered. I want the $onDestroy to deregister the click event, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass function reference to `on` & `off` method as in parameter. You don't need to pass whole click function reference.

**Code**

```
this.$onInit = function() {
    listener = function () {
        console.log('You clicked on the document');
    };
    $document.on('click', listener); 
}

this.$onDestroy = function() {
    console.log('$onDestory triggered');
    $document.off('click', listener);
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tu55cman/) Here